# Adding Rails data to Highcharts series

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I am trying to make a chart to display a users weight, using highcharts. I have all of the correct js files included and when passed a simple array of integers, it works just fine. 
However I am unsure, having read the highcharts docs, how to pass the correct data into the series options using rails.

my user model is as follows:

A user has many weigh_ins, which has weight:float user_id:integer id:integer created_at:datetime fields. (if this is relevant)

Below is my view, as you can see i have tried to iterate through the users weights and then pass that as the data. I know it needs to be fed json and an array, but im not sure how to format my data to fit in that way.

```
   borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
                    name: 'weight',
                    data: <% @user.weigh_ins.each do |weight| %>
                                            <%= weight.weight.to_json %>
                                            <% end %>


            }]
```

If there is any more code that needs posting, just shout.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thata defo on the right track, however, the data is dynamic so a user can update their weights everyday, so the chart needs to update aswell. If i use the square brackets like above then the graph doesnt even render. Now i have this but it doesnt produce the correct output either. I need to find the weigh_ins for the correct user, then iterate through all of them and select the weight figure which is a float. Not sure how to tackle it.

```
 data: <% user = @user.weigh_ins %> 
       <% user.each do |user_weight| %> 
       [<%= user_weight.weight %> ] 
       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm something similar with this code:

```
<% bio_array = Array.new(@bio.size) %>

<% @biometrics.each_with_index {|x, index| %>
    <% bio_array += [x[:weight]]    %>
<% } %>

(... some code ...)

series: [{
        name: 'Some Name',
        data: <%= bio_array %>
```

Please note that this code is not optimized for you case (in my case i have other logic that i omitted for being useless to your case - i had a multidimensional arrays with [data and value]).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to parse data like that , you don't really have to use Json , becoz since yo don't  update dynamically , you can just echo it like [34,32,24,25,12] bt first you hv to make that String from Ruby , and that's exactly what is json is used for too , check your Json output,
btw try echo some Ruby String like

```
 => 1,2,3,4,5 [<% echo str %> ]
```

and if your json out put hv no squre brackets [] then try adding them

```
 data:[ <% @user.weigh_ins.each do |weight| %> ]
```